# How to get webcam feed in chrome extension persistently when chrome is open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getusermedia, webcam-capture

I am trying to make a chrome extension where I need access to the webcam feed once the user has allowed permission and has toggled on button in the extension popup. The feed should (and the extension) should keep running persistently until the user has stopped the feed via the control in the popup or has exited chrome.

Unfortunately, there's not sufficient information as to how to do this, let alone access webcam from the extension. I did read the related answer where its mentioned to use content scripts but there's no example code for it. (And no documentation as well).

Also, unfortunately I don't have enough working code to give insight of my progress.

Comment: Suggestion: get this working from a web page (which must be delivered via localhost or https) and then work out how to put it in the `background.js` for a Web Extension. You'll probably have to get camera-access permission for the extension in a popup page. This may work differently in different browsers. For example see this.  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1278100